# выбор в Combobox c# согласно запросу

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

Добрый день, проблема у меня возникла такова.
Есть combobox в нее подгружаются данные из dataset,

```
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(type, con);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();

        cb_opf.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        cb_opf.DisplayMember = "short";
        cb_opf.ValueMember = "code";
```

на форме есть поле в которое пользователь вводит данные и нажимает кнопку "Заполнить" 
Ответ приходит в формате json в котором есть поле "code" со значениями.
Как то вот нужно связать поле code из ответа и valueMember из combobox так чтобы выборе выбиралось значение в combobox.

Comment: Не ясно. Заполняет пользователь форму, затем отправляется куда-то запрос и ответ возвращается в виде `json`. Так? А дальше что вам нужно распарсить `json` и вытащить из него значение по ключу `key`?

Comment: Да, ответ приходит в формате json, данные уже из него я вытащит теперь надо принудительно выбрать значение из combobox. Т.е.: значение из ответа json code: 1234 в combobox есть значения 1111, 1222, 1333, 1234.

Comment: как теперь выбрать значение в combobox?

Comment: `cb_opf.SelectedValue = code;`?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался

```
combobox.SelectedValue = response.suggestionss[0].code;
```

выбирается нужное значение в combobox